# Scan complete directory tree using pep8

Tags: python, pep8-checker

I'm using pep8 to check for coding guidelines. I am getting results only for the current directory. And not all directory or sub directory inside it. How to do that?

When running it from the level of container/project, I don't get pyc files' errors. When I run it from container/project/app, I get the pyc files' errors. Following is the tree structure:

```
container
      project
            app
                  __init__.py
                  admin.py
                  models.py
                  views.py
                  tests.py
                  file1.py

            project
                  __init__.py
                  urls.py
                  wsgi.py
                  settings.py

            templates
                  __init__.py
                  home.html
                  page1.html

            manage.py
            pylintrc
            setup.cfg

      README
```

And following is the content of setup.cfg:

```
[pep8]
ignore=E122,E123,E128
exclude=pylintrc,setup.cfg
max-line-length=80
```

Comment: You mean you are using the [`pep8` command line tool](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? It will scan subdirectories if the argument is a directory name, unless you excluded them with the `--exclude` option. How are you calling it?

Comment: I've edited the question including details. I run from command line `pep8 *`

Comment: Why not use `pep8 .` instead?

Comment: I just did that after removing the ignore and exclude sections from the setup.cfg file. But it gives errors related to settings.py, urls.py and file1.py. No pylintrc, no setup.cfg, no pyc related errors.

Comment: `pep8` will by default only scan for `.py` files in directories, it *will* traverse subdirectories. What makes you think it is skipping subdirectories for you?

Comment: In fact, `settings.py` and `urls.py` and `file1.py` are in two different subdirectories, so the command *works*. What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: I have got this part. It is working for the --filename parameter that defaults to *.py files. I was expecting the same. And yes it does scan all non-py files in the current directory. But not in the subsequent child directories. So, I got just curious, why doesn't it scan non-py files in the child directories, since they are also present in the `*` wild card and am neither excluding them as well.

Comment: That's not how it works, it is your *shell or console* that expands the wildcard. `pep8` is handed a list of names, not `*`. If you wanted `pep8` to scan all subdirectories using the `*` wildcard, you need to tell it to so with `--filename='*'`.

Comment: Thanks. Also, can you help me understand, what is the root or root path of the project? It should be `container/project` . But am confused since it doesn't have an __init__.py file. I face frequent problems related to python paths. SO it would help me understand it.

Comment: Your `container/python` root contains packages, it is not *itself* a package. You don't use `from python.app import admin`, you use `from app import admin`.

Comment: So, `container/project` is the root and it should be present in the python path?

Comment: This looks like a Django project to me; `container/project` would be part of the Python path, yes.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Hope to hear from you on my future questions as well. :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `pep8` command *does* scan subdirectories automatically. It'll look for any file matching the patterns named in the `--filename` option (the default is `*.py`).

Scan your project with `pep8 .` or `pep8 directoryname`.

If you run `pep8 *` in a directory, then your shell expands the `*` into *all files* in the current directory, so `pep8` will scan all those files even if they don't match the `--filename` file patterns. That could include files like `setup.cfg`, which is not a file you'd want to scan.

Any subdirectories of the current directory would still be scanned too (as they are named in the list of names the shell produces when you use the `*` wildcard), but then `pep8` will only look for files matching the `--filename` option again.